# MongoDB Rust Client Connection Errors

Tags: mongodb, rust

I am a Rust newbie and am trying to create a REST API using actix and mongodb.

Before starting up the I am trying to connect to a local MongoDB instance Using the official rust client from [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-rust-driver). Here is the code I am trying

```
let client = Client::with_uri_str("mongodb://localhost:27017").expect("Error getting client");
let database = client.database("mydb");
let collection = database.collection("books");
```

Rustc version is 1.44 and MongoDB driver version 1.0.0

While running this code, I do not get an error if the local mongodb server is not running.

How do we figure out if the connection to the DB has been successful or not ? No point continuing if the DB connection itself is not established.

Comment: It could be the case that the client only creates connections when necessary. Why not just issue a dummy query?

Answer (score 2):

The drivers are required to establish connections in the background. Instantiating a client is supposed to always succeed.

The purpose of this is to, for example, allow the application and the database to be started at the same time - when the database becomes available, the application will be able to use it.

To find out whether your database is operational, execute a command such as `ping`. Most applications will simply carry on with their normal queries/updates.

Comment: Have implemented a ping as suggested and it works well. 
Coming from a Java/SpringBoot background, this looks to be a strange behaviour though. I think the driver should not let the client instantiation succeed if the database is not available.

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring.rst#clients-do-no-i-o-in-the-constructor

Comment: How do you implement such a "ping" with the mongodb rust driver?